# Text-Based Game Assistance

Tags: python

I have been assigned to create a text-based game. I can go in all directions no problem, but when I go to "get" the item or contents of the room, it displays my "Else" message: "I don't see that here."
How can I correct this and be sure it is added to my `Inventory`?

Below is what I have so far:

```
#Start

rooms = {
    'Entrance': {'name': 'Entrance', 'North': 'Food Area', 'East': 'Carousel', 'West': 'Game Area',
                 'content': 'none', 'text': 'The Entrance'},

    'Carousel': {'name': 'Carousel', 'West': 'Entrance', 'contents': ['balloon animal'],
                 'text': 'This is the Carousel. Grab the Balloon Animal.'},

    'Game Area': {'name': 'Game Area', 'North': 'FunHouse', 'East': 'Entrance', 'contents': ['big red shoes'],
                  'text': 'This is the Game Area. Grab the Big Red Shoes.'},

    'Food Area': {'name': 'Food Area', 'South': 'Entrance', 'East': 'Tilt-O-Whirl', 'North': 'Ferris Wheel',
                  'contents': ['red nose'], 'text': 'This is the Food Area. Grab the Red Nose.'},

    'Ferris Wheel': {'name': 'Ferris Wheel', 'South': 'Food Area', 'contents': ['clown suit'],
                     'text': 'This is the Ferris Wheel. Grab the Clown Suit.'},

    'Roller Coaster': {'name': 'Roller Coaster', 'South': 'Tilt-O-Whirl', 'contents': ['blow torch'],
                       'text': 'This is the Roller Coaster. Grab the Blow Torch.'},

    'Tilt-O-Whirl': {'name': 'Tilt-O-Whirl', 'North': 'Roller Coaster', 'West': 'Food Area',
                     'contents': ['rainbow wig'], 'text': 'This is the Tilt-O-Whirl. Grab the Rainbow Wig.'},

    'FunHouse': {'name': 'FunHouse', 'South': 'Game Area', 'contents': ['clown'],
                 'text': 'This is the FunHouse. Beat the Clown!'}
}
directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']
currentRoom = rooms['Entrance']
Inventory = []


def show_instructions():
    # print a main menu and the commands
    print('-------------------------------------------------------')
    print("Welcome to A Day at the Fair")
    print("Collect all 6 items while avoiding the clown or be captured by Nickel Knowing")
    print("Move commands: South, North, East, West")
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'contents'")
    print('-------------------------------------------------------')


show_instructions()

while True:
    # display current location
    print('You are in {}.'.format(currentRoom['text']))
    # get user input
    command = input('\nWhat do you do? ').strip()
    # movement
    if command in directions:
        if command in currentRoom:
            currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom[command]]
        else:
            # bad movement
            print("You cant go that way.")
    # quit game
    elif command.lower() in ('q', 'quit'):
        break
    # bad command
    elif command.lower().split()[0] == 'get':
        item = command.lower().split()[1]
        if item in [x.lower() for x in currentRoom['contents']]:
            Inventory.append(item)
            print('You grabbed {}.'.format(currentRoom['contents']))
        else:
            print("I don't see that here.")
while currentRoom in ['FunHouse']:
    if len(Inventory) == 6:
        print('You collected all of the items, and defeated Nickel Knowing the Clown!')
    else:
       print('It looks like you have not found everything, you lose!')
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that when you check for `[x.lower() for x in currentRoom['contents']]`, you end up searching for a list instead of a string (i.e. checking for '[big red shoes]' instead of just 'big red shoes'). Replace that line with just `currentRoom['contents']`. Also replace `item = command.lower().split()[1]` with `item = " ".join(command.lower().split()[1:])` because you want not just the first word after "get", but the rest of the phrase itself.

Full code:

```
rooms = {
    'Entrance': {'name': 'Entrance', 'North': 'Food Area', 'East': 'Carousel', 'West': 'Game Area',
                 'content': 'none', 'text': 'The Entrance'},

    'Carousel': {'name': 'Carousel', 'West': 'Entrance', 'contents': ['balloon animal'],
                 'text': 'This is the Carousel. Grab the Balloon Animal.'},

    'Game Area': {'name': 'Game Area', 'North': 'FunHouse', 'East': 'Entrance', 'contents': ['big red shoes'],
                  'text': 'This is the Game Area. Grab the Big Red Shoes.'},

    'Food Area': {'name': 'Food Area', 'South': 'Entrance', 'East': 'Tilt-O-Whirl', 'North': 'Ferris Wheel',
                  'contents': ['red nose'], 'text': 'This is the Food Area. Grab the Red Nose.'},

    'Ferris Wheel': {'name': 'Ferris Wheel', 'South': 'Food Area', 'contents': ['clown suit'],
                     'text': 'This is the Ferris Wheel. Grab the Clown Suit.'},

    'Roller Coaster': {'name': 'Roller Coaster', 'South': 'Tilt-O-Whirl', 'contents': ['blow torch'],
                       'text': 'This is the Roller Coaster. Grab the Blow Torch.'},

    'Tilt-O-Whirl': {'name': 'Tilt-O-Whirl', 'North': 'Roller Coaster', 'West': 'Food Area',
                     'contents': ['rainbow wig'], 'text': 'This is the Tilt-O-Whirl. Grab the Rainbow Wig.'},

    'FunHouse': {'name': 'FunHouse', 'South': 'Game Area', 'contents': ['clown'],
                 'text': 'This is the FunHouse. Beat the Clown!'}
}
directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']
currentRoom = rooms['Entrance']
Inventory = []


def show_instructions():
    # print a main menu and the commands
    print('-------------------------------------------------------')
    print("Welcome to A Day at the Fair")
    print("Collect all 6 items while avoiding the clown or be captured by Nickel Knowing")
    print("Move commands: South, North, East, West")
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'contents'")
    print('-------------------------------------------------------')


show_instructions()

while True:
    # display current location
    print('You are in {}.'.format(currentRoom['text']))
    # get user input
    command = input('\nWhat do you do? ').strip()
    # movement
    if command in directions:
        if command in currentRoom:
            currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom[command]]
        else:
            # bad movement
            print("You cant go that way.")
    # quit game
    elif command.lower() in ('q', 'quit'):
        break
    # bad command
    elif command.lower().split()[0] == 'get':
        item = " ".join(command.lower().split()[1:])
        if item in currentRoom['contents']:
            Inventory.append(item)
            print('You grabbed {}.'.format(currentRoom['contents']))
        else:
            print("I don't see that here.")
while currentRoom in ['FunHouse']:
    if len(Inventory) == 6:
        print('You collected all of the items, and defeated Nickel Knowing the Clown!')
    else:
       print('It looks like you have not found everything, you lose!')
    break
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm able to grab the item but I can't seem to move to the next room after I grab the item. Is my loop incomplete?

Comment: @LeeLee it works for me. I'm not sure what went wrong...

Comment: After I obtain the Item and it prompts "What do you do?" I type in a new direction and it stays in the same room.